# How can I run a Django server in the Ubuntu subsytem for Windows 10?

Tags: django, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used these commands (Ubuntu Bash in Windows 10 subsystem):

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ cd ~
$ virtual venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install django
(venv) $ django-admin startproject mysite
(venv) $ cd mysite
(venv) $ python managy.py makemigrations
(venv) $ python managy.py migrate
(venv) $ python managy.py runserver
...
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

...
```

(in Windows 10)
open web browser
typed in URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
... no response....

Did I miss something? [This video](https://godjango.com/123-django-with-bash-for-windows/) show it working, but for me, it doesn't.

Comment: try a different port - python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:9595 - and see what happens

Comment: I placed it as answer form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your port 8000 could be in use. Run the server on a different port num.

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:9595
```